# Add In Text/HTML After Woocommerce Product Page Description

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I'm having issues concatenating text/html to the Woocommerce product page description based on the product's category.

I've added the following to my functions.php theme file:

```
    add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 'caution_text');

    function caution_text($desc){
        if(is_product_category('stone')){
            $desc .= 'Text/HTML To Add';
        }
        return $desc;
    }
```

I've tried it both with and without the product category check and it still is not concatenating the text, so I'm inclined to think I've created my filter wrong.

For reference, I'm using the StoreFront theme with some custom modifications, none of which should be causing conflicts with this.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know about woocommerce, but in PHP, if `$desc` is null, the `.=` will fail.  You should have a check: `if(isset($desc)){$desc.="Text/HTML to Add";}else{$desc="Text/HTML to Add";}`.

Answer (score 0):

The code isn't working because `is_product_category()` checks whether you're viewing a product category. The code runs on the single product page therefore will always evaluate to false.

Use `has_term()` instead.

Replace:

```
if(is_product_category('stone')){
```

With:

```
if ( has_term( 'stone', 'product_cat' ) ) {
```

Further reading: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term

Comment: Thanks for that, that will help with one portion, but I'm still have issue.
I mentioned in my original post that I have tried it both with and without the product category check and it still is not working :(.